# Can't tell if APC is "working"... Hits/Misses + varnish

Tags: nginx, apc, varnish, php

Alright, so I installed nginx, php-fpm, apc and varnish and while it all "works" in terms of no errors, I'm unsure how to tell if/what they are caching...

Now, I'm on CentOS 6 and I installed APC with:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc
```

so this might be why it's not working (if it isn't) at all, or at least seems like it's not working with the apc.php that comes with APC (as installing it like I did, I didn't get it, I had to extract it from the package and then upload it) but all I'm seeing is:

1 Hit
0 Misses

System Cache Entries shows nothing for Script Filename, nothing for Hits, Size 656 and surprisingly it's saying it was last accessed AND created at: 1970/01/01 00:00:00 and then last modified was at 2pm today?

Per-directory resources has nothing for directory, 35 filenames, 0 hits, 421264 for size

NOW, I also have a apc2.php which is just: `<?php print_r(apc_cache_info()); ?>`

and that shows:

```
Array
(
[nslots] => 4099
[ttl] => 7200
[nhits] => 1208
[nmisses] => 233
[ninserts] => 53
[nentries] => 35
[nexpunges] => 0
[stime] => 1382663331
[mem_size] => 421264
[file_upload_progress] => 1
[memory_type] => mmap
[cache_list] => Array
```

and then lists a bunch of WP/W3TC related items

Any particular reason for the discrepancies there?

Final question, is there anyway (outside of varnish simply inserting the header) to tell if varnish is actually caching anything?

Answer (score 0):

To tell if Varnish is caching and how it is going I like to do the following:

```
varnishstat -f cache_hit,cache_miss,cache_hitpass,n_gzip,n_gunzip,n_lru_nuked,n_expired
```

That is the main stats I like to watch. It'll update real time.

The output will be something like this:

```
    0+19:43:40 Hitrate ratio:       10       19       19
Hitrate avg:     0.8497   0.8673   0.8673

       35304         0.00         0.50 cache_hit - Cache hits
        1026         0.00         0.01 cache_hitpass - Cache hits for pass
        4721         0.00         0.07 cache_miss - Cache misses
        2215          .            .   n_expired - N expired objects
          86         0.00         0.00 n_gzip - Gzip operations
        3549         0.00         0.05 n_gunzip - Gunzip operations
```

Your APC problem seems weird. All I can tell you is to make sure you have enabled it.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/apc.configuration.php
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enabled

Also, try to complete your profile here on Stackoverflow, set up a user name etc.
Most people will not bother to anwser a question if they think there is a change the user that asked it will not accept it nor participate in the question.

Best regards.